# Odata producer and consumer scala play

Tags: scala, playframework, odata

Is there Odata available for play using scala. Can you point me approprite example/tutorial? What I foud online were for Odata4j which was java library. I didn't get how to set up the odata producers endpoint.

What I beleive is there should be simple and straightforward way to do it.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Apache Olingo project is very active communiity. Its a java library & is easily inter-operable in scala.